# Python error numpy.int32 object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a below python code which detect person in frame. Once detected, it get the bounding box of the person which is `person_box`. From `person_box` I can get the `startX, startY` and `width height` of the bounding box. But in below code, in for loop, I am getting error as `numpy.int32 object is not iterable`

```
person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
person_box = person_box.astype(int)
print(person_box)
(startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")
width = endX - startX
height = endY - startY

for (startX, startY, width, height) in person_box:
    person_box = np.array([startX, startY, startX + width, startY + height])
```

output

```
[159 156 451 431]
```

I am not able to understand the error much as I am not much experienced with numpy arrays. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Show a traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop will iterate `person_box` and pass parameter by parameter. You are trying to split the parameter and assign to `startX, startY, width, height` in `for (startX, startY, width, height) in person_box:` you can just try:

```
person_box = np.array([person_box [0], person_box[1] , person_box[0] + person_box[2] , person_box[1] + person_box[3] ])
```

or

```
startX = person_box[0]
startY = person_box[1]
width = person_box[2]
height = person_box[3]
person_box = np.array([startX, startY, startX + width, startY + height])
```